# Drupal Views: Filter content based on menu links

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I try to make a view which lists all linked sub nodes from a specific menu item. So let's say we have the following a menu:

```
- Home
- About us
- Modules
  - Module A
  - Module B
  - Module C
```

I like to be able to get all nodes in a view which are attached to the `Modules` menu item.

Is there any module which can help me with this? Or does the Views module provide a solution out of the box for that?

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming you know how to create a view that displays all nodes associated with "Modules", all you need to do is use "Contextual Filters" to do it instead of regular filters.

Regular filters are something that you can either set or allow the user set himself. What you need though is to get this as a parameter from the URL, so each one of those menu links will provide a different filter to the view and just display the nodes you want - and that's what Contextual Filters allows you to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `create a view that displays all nodes associated with "Modules"` this is exactly what I'm looking for. But I don't know how to do that in `Views`.

Comment: I found this question and answer. The question is exactly what I like to do but the answer doesn't work: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/15087/23215